# JPA, error in meta-data for CLASS: more than one primary key field

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, metadata

I have a parent and a child class. When I run the app I'm getting following error:

```
Error in meta-data for com.twitterjaya.model.HistoryDeviceJPA: More than one primary key field.
```

I have no idea why it says I defined more than one primary key. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
@Entity(name = "HistoryJPA")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorValue("HistoryJPA")
public class HistoryJPA {

    @Id
    String pageAddress;
    String domain;
    String pageTitle;
    long pageVisits;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        HistoryJPA that = (HistoryJPA) o;

        if (!pageAddress.equals(that.pageAddress)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return pageAddress.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HistoryJPA{" +
                "pageAddress='" + pageAddress + '\'' +
                ", domain='" + domain + '\'' +
                ", pageTitle='" + pageTitle + '\'' +
                ", pageVisits=" + pageVisits +
                '}';
    }

    public String getPageAddress() {
        return pageAddress;
    }

    public void setPageAddress(String pageAddress) {
        this.pageAddress = pageAddress;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public String getPageTitle() {
        return pageTitle;
    }

    public void setPageTitle(String pageTitle) {
        this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
    }

    public long getPageVisits() {
        return pageVisits;
    }

    public void setPageVisits(long pageVisits) {
        this.pageVisits = pageVisits;
    }
}
```

and child class:

```
@Entity(name = "HistoryDeviceJPA")
@DiscriminatorValue("HistoryDeviceJPA")
public class HistoryDeviceJPA extends HistoryJPA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userUUID;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

        HistoryDeviceJPA that = (HistoryDeviceJPA) o;

        if (!id.equals(that.id)) return false;
        if (!userUUID.equals(that.userUUID)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + userUUID.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HistoryDeviceJPA{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userUUID='" + userUUID + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getUserUUID() {
        return userUUID;
    }

    public void setUserUUID(String userUUID) {
        this.userUUID = userUUID;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by the error message, you have two primary keys (annotated with `@Id`):

- one in `HistoryJPA` on field `pageAddress`
- one in `HistoryDeviceJPA` on field `id`

You should get rid of one of them, or create a [composite primary key](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm#BCGGGDDC) depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I found this document useful as well: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance